# Why variables in function scope and method scope differs?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-v5.1

I use to log the function name which has exception . The code is as below

```
function sample {
    try{
        $functionname = "sample"
        throw "Error"
    }
    catch{
        write-error "[$functionName] :Exception occured "
        $_
    }
}

sample
```

Now the same thing i am trying to follow in class method. But the variable declared in try block is not visible in catch block.

```
class sample{

[string] samplemethod() {

    try{
        $MethodName = "SampleMethod"

        throw "error"

    }
    catch{
        Write-error "[$MethodName] : Exception occured"

        $_
    }
    return "err"
}

}

$obj = [sample]::new()
$obj.samplemethod()
```

It throws exception as below

> At line:12 char:23
>   +         Write-error "[$MethodName] : Exception occured"
>   +                       ~~~~~~~~~~~ Variable is not assigned in the method.

Whether scope rule changed between class method and function?

Comment: Parser simply more strict for classes. It not allow to read variable, if it is not guaranteed to be assigned in the method before use. Although it is easy to bypass. According to my knowledge, there are no scope rule changes here.

Answer (score -1):

There is different scope exist in try catch blocks in addition to Class and methods.The variables declared in try block can not access from catch block. The below code should execute without any exception.
    class sample{

```
[string] samplemethod() {
    $MethodName = "SampleMethod1"

    try{
        $test='hello'

        throw "error"

    }
    catch{
        Write-Host $MethodName
        Write-error "[$MethodName] : Exception occured"

        $_
    }
    return "err"
}

}

$obj = [sample]::new()
$obj.samplemethod()
```